# Deleted gnome desktop environment on fedora now I'm stuck at command line login

Tags: fedora, gnome

I am using fedora 28. I had enough of the staggering terminal in gnome (mem leak I think) so I installed cinnamon. The problem is thought uninstaling gnome would just automatically set the DE to cinnamon.

How do i set the default DE to cinnamon in my current state?

Comment: Install a display manager.

Comment: You will get a better answer on https://unix.stackexchange.com/  (Wild guess try `apt get-install cinnamon` again. Possibly it would not "steal" default desktop when it saw Gnome installed, but will now that there is no other window manager?)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Cinnamon user myself and would recommend you reinstall Gnome for a couple of reasons.  First, you'll probably still want to run the Gnome Display Manager (uninstalling that is probably why you're at a command line.)  Second, Cinnamon depends on some of the core Gnome libraries so you're not really saving much by uninstalling Gnome.  Third, and most importantly, you will probably run into the occasional issue after upgrades and having both Gnome and Cinnamon installed allows you to switch between the two environments to more easily isolate issues.  With both installed, all you need to do is click the gear icon in the display manager login screen and select Cinnamon or Gnome as your DE. (it's a sticky setting so you only need to do it when you want to change)

Comment: Fedora uses gnome 4. Cinnamon is best on gnome 2.

Comment: Either you meant Gnome 3 or you're writing this from the future (Gnome 3.30 was just released September 5th ;-)  Cinnamon works beautifully with the Gnome 3 libraries (i.e. hardware accelerated) for me with none of the stutter and sluggishness I experienced with Gnome 3 itself.   There is definitely also software fallback mode (don't think it's still based on Gnome 2 though) if your system can't support hardware acceleration.